# Brochure Design: For a saddle stitch (center stapled) brochure, what adjustments should be made to compensate for creep?

Tags: print-design, book, print-production

For a saddle stitch (center-stapled) brochure, what adjustments should be made (if any) to counter any page-size distortion from folding?

I know measures are taken to mitigate this with other types of brochure (trifold, etc.). But, is it common practise to adjust the center pages of a *saddle stitch brochure* to prevent creep, when the brochure is closed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found some info on this, afterall. However I'm still unsure as to any "manual" measures that can be taken in larger publications...

> **Shingling:**
>
> A means of positioning type in books, magazines, newsletters, or other
>   publications designed to be bound by means of saddle-stitching that
>   compensates for creep, an increasing book thickness through the
>   interior of the publication, by progressively narrowing the bind
>   margin from the outside pages to the center pages, and increasing the
>   bind margin from the center pages to the back pages. Shingling is
>   performed so that text appears to be in the same position on all
>   pages.
>   [Source](http://printwiki.org/Shingling)

It appears this is a responsibility of printers during the imposition process:

> Generally, designers aren't expected to do shingling. It's done by the
>   print service provider as part of the imposition process, which
>   positions individual pages correctly for final printing, trimming, and
>   binding. But when your project has images that spread across pages or
>   has tight crossovers between pages, your design will need to be
>   adjusted before printing to ensure spread elements aren't adversely
>   affected during imposition.

[Source](http://www.cedargraphicsinc.com/Resource-Center/Multipage/Fixing-Shingling-Creeping-and-Feathering)

Comment: As you noted, this is usually done by the actual printer during imposition. For larger publications, saddle-stitch is generally avoided - it doesn't scale up well for large quantities and/or thick pages.